# Download file from server folder to client pc

Tags: javascript

How can you download a file (.mp3) from a publicly accessible folder on the server to the clients pc?

I have tried:

```
let url = "\\public\\test.mp3";
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    // xhr.response is a blob
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); 
    a.download = 'test.mp3';
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
};

xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

But this just downloads the file with 15KB not the entire thing

Comment: Do you have to use XHR to download the file?

Comment: Perhaps you should be using asynchronous xhr... synchronous method is deprecated. [`xhr.open('GET', url, true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open). Also, I highly doubt that path is valid. Try using forward slashes for fetching a resource from a server, as in `/public/test.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

Just navigate the user to the mp3 file:

`window.location.href = '\\public\\test.mp3';`